# Descending Asterisk Stars with Javascript Do while loops

Tags: javascript, do-while

I am doing a little review in loops as assigned by my teacher. He wants us to make descending and ascending sets of stars like:

%%%%

%%%

%%

%

%

%%

%%%

%%%%

What I have so far is:

```
var a=1, b=1;

do
{
    do
    {
        document.write("*");
        a++;
    }while(a<=10);
document.write("<br>");
b++;
}while(b<=10);
```

which outputs this:

```
%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
%
%
%
%
%
%
%
```

I've tried messing with the while statements but it usually results in an infinite loop.

I have the second triangle star part done with a for loop:

```
for(var b=1;b<=10;b++){
 for(var c=1;c<=b;c++){
    document.write("*");
}
 document.write("<br>");
}
```

But he wants them in do while loops so I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Sorry guys. I have apparantly mislead you guys a little. What I meant was that the descending and ascending stars were seperate codes. Thank you for the combined ones, but that isn't right. Very Sorry!

Comment: Reset `a` once you leave the inner loop.

Comment: How do you mean? You mean move a++ to the outer loop?

Comment: Instead of writing `"*"`, write `a` (not `"a"`, `a`!).

Comment: Got a solution for you, check it out.

Comment: Can you use more than one do/while loop (not nested?) If so that would probably be the easiest approach. For fun, [here is one with a single do-while loop](http://jsbin.com/hunepamiki/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing two loops, one for descending and one for ascending, is probably the easiest approach.

Note: [Array.fill in the below code is not supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) (Hello, IE!)

```js
/* char is optional. if not supplied, it will use '%' */
function draw(howMany, char) {
  var lines = howMany;
  /* Build a string of howMany chars */
//      var str = (new Array(howMany)).fill(char || '%').join("");
  // Since some browsers don't support Array.fill
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
      str += char || '%';
  }
  /* Descending */
  do {
    document.write(str.substr(0, lines--) + "<br>");
  } while (lines > 0);
  /* Ascending */
  lines = 1;
  do {
    document.write(str.substr(0, lines++) + "<br>");
  } while (lines <= howMany);
}

draw(10);
document.write("<br>");
draw(10, '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do:

```
var a=1, b=10, asc = false;
var fn = function() {
  return function(a, b) {
    return (a) ? ++b : --b;
  };
};

do {
    a = 1;
    do {
        document.write("*");
    } while(a++<=b);
    document.write("<br>");
    b = fn()(asc, b);
    (!b) && (document.write("*<br>"));
    (!!b) || (asc = true);
} while(b<=10);
```

As can be [seen here](https://jsbin.com/ledefixosu/1/edit?js,output), but seriously: you should not use SO for your assignments. That's only preventing you to bite the bullet and learn to solve programming problems.

Comment: This does not yield the same output. In the original post when the count is 1, it gets duplicated